# Web Data Transfer and API

Tags: php, api, curl

I learning about programming, data transfer over the web and APIs.  I created a simple model of a data transfer between two websites.  I have three basic questions about the below process.  In reviewing, assume both websites are setup with TLS.

1. Would the below simple process be a good secure architecture for data transfer between two websites?
2. Would this simple example be called an API?
3. In this example how could additional security be implemented (i.e. API Key etc..)?

Website 1 - A simple web form to capture and send data:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="include/redirect.php">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Website 1 Include file that runs on submissions of the form:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']!="") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $url = "https://localhost/api/api/".$name;

    $client = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $response = curl_exec($client);
    
    $result = json_decode($response);
    
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>Name:</td><td>$result->name</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Amount:</td><td>$result->amount</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Response Code:</td><td>$result->response_code</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Response Desc:</td><td>$result->response_desc</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

}
?>
```

Website 2 - Called in the include file: https://localhost/api/api/".$name;.  Website 2 receives data and assigns an amount to it and returns the data.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
if (isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name']!="") {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
}
else {
    response(NULL, NULL, 400,"Can't process options now, visit local dealer");
}

if($name=="Joe"){
    
    $amount = "700";
    $response_code = "Good";
    $response_desc = "Good";
    response($name, $amount, $response_code,$response_desc);
}
else {
        
    response(NULL, NULL, 200,"Can't process options now, visit local dealer");
  
}


function response($name,$amount,$response_code,$response_desc){
    $response['name'] = $name;
    $response['amount'] = $amount;
    $response['response_code'] = $response_code;
    $response['response_desc'] = $response_desc;
    
    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Would the below simple process be a good secure architecture for data transfer between two websites?

Yes, this can work. If you just want the two web servers to communicate with each other I would recommend limiting access to the script via a .htaccess file or a firewall though so it's not publicly accessible.

Of course, wherever possible calling methods via PHP instead of sending HTTP requests between scripts is more secure, faster and better in almost any way.

### Would this simple example be called an API?

> An application programming interface (API) is a connection between computers or between computer programs. It is a type of software interface, offering a service to other pieces of software.
> From [Wikipedia: API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)

Well yes, you have implemented an API. Your computer is able to communicate with the server to send and receive data and your two websites/servers can also communicate with and offer services to each other.

### In this example how could additional security be implemented (i.e. API Key etc..)?

As I've mentioned earlier, depending on your requirements you can limit access to the API endpoint used for server to server communication ("https://localhost/api/api" in this case) to prevent someone other than your server from using it (Use a .htaccess file or check for the IP in the code)

Further, there are a few ways to prevent spoofing attacks in the server to server part of it, including [(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook#Authenticating_the_webhook_notification):

- Using HTTP basic authentication (or OAuth if you want to go way further)
- Using a shared secret (API Key)
- Including a signature to verify the contents have not been changed (e.g. HMAC, see [Is HMAC required when using TLS communication?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213292/is-hmac-required-when-using-tls-communication))

This is by no means comprehensive, I hope it could povide some answers and points to research further.